# how to implement a unique key when add a new record in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have 2 order tables(master/detail). 1 is the order header, another one is in detail. 2 tables are linked (master.key_seq = detail.link_key_seq).
I just dragged this two table to a form as datagridviews. This form is working properly with update/insert/delete from sql server. 
How can I implement a unique key number when I press the "add" button from the bindingNavigator ?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace TestConnect
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        private void mPO_MASTERBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Validate();
                this.mPO_MASTERBindingSource.EndEdit();
               this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.vGB_PurchaseDataSet);
            }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'vGB_PurchaseDataSet.MPO_DETAIL' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.mPO_DETAILTableAdapter.Fill(this.vGB_PurchaseDataSet.MPO_DETAIL);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'vGB_PurchaseDataSet.MPO_MASTER' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.mPO_MASTERTableAdapter.Fill(this.vGB_PurchaseDataSet.MPO_MASTER);
        }

    private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.mPO_DETAILDataGridView.SelectedRows)
        {
            mPO_DETAILDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        }
        }
    }
    }
```